# React MUI - overriding styling for selected tab not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a project built with [React mui v3](https://v3.material-ui.com/). In my component I would like to override the styling for the selected tab, by setting the border-bottom to a different value from the other tabs.
I have tried doing that first on the component level by setting classes and selected property with new styling:

```
tab: {
    color: '#077197',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '0.9rem',
    borderBottom: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
},
selected: {
    border: `1px solid ${theme.palette.divider}`,
    borderBottom: '1px solid white',
    background: 'white',
  },
```

And use it on the tab:

```
<Tab value="1" label="First value"
           classes={{root: classes.tab, selected: classes.selected}}/>
```

But, in the console I could see that the selected class is overridden by the tab selected styling. I have also tried to do it on the theme level, by setting the `MuiTab` to this:

```
MuiTab: {
  selected: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    border: "1px solid white",
    color: orange[700],
    "&:hover": {
      color: green[700]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui3-how-to-override-tab-theme-3tpv7).
But, that didn't work, how can you override then the styling for selected tab?

Answer (score 1):

in your example, in the console you can read:

Material-UI: The `MuiTab` component increases the CSS specificity of the `selected` internal state.
You can not override it like this:

```
{

  "root": {

    "&:hover": {

      "backgroundColor": "white",

      "color": "#c2185b",

      "border": "1px solid black"

    }

  },

  "selected": {

    "backgroundColor": "white",

    "border": "1px solid white",

    "color": "#f57c00",

    "&:hover": {

      "color": "#388e3c"

    }

  }

}
```

Instead, you need to use the $ruleName syntax:

```
{

  "root": {

    "&$selected": {

      "backgroundColor": "white",

      "border": "1px solid white",

      "color": "#f57c00",

      "&:hover": {

        "color": "#388e3c"

      }

    }

  }

}
```